# react-apollo GraphQL query - this.client.watchQuery is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

```
export default graphql(queryShippingRates, {
    options: props => ({
        variables: {
            id: props.navigation.state.params.checkout.id
        },
        pollInterval: 5000,
        client: {
            apolloclient: props.navigation.state.params.apolloclient
        }
    }),

    props: ({
        data
    }) => {
        if (data.loading) {
            return {
                fetchNextPage: () => {}
            };
        } else if (!data.node.availableShippingRates.ready) {
            return {
                fetchNextPage: () => {}
            };
        } else if (!data) {
            return {
                fetchNextPage: () => {}
            };
        } else if (data.error) {
            console.warn('error', data.error);
        }

        const fetchNextPage = () => {
            return data.fetchMore({
                updateQuery: (previousResult, {
                    fetchMoreResult
                }) => {
                    return {
                        node: fetchMoreResult.data.node,
                    };
                },
            });
        };
        console.log(fetchNextPage);

        return {
            data: data,
        };
    },
})(CheckoutShippingMethodScreen);
```

I am using the code above to send a graphQL query via react-apollo. As you can see above, I placed a prop within options to specify which client to use when sending the Query. When I run the code, I get an error saying that `this.client.watchQuery` is not a function.

I have the app wrapped by an ApolloProvider Component with a specified client, but I read that you can place a custom client as a prop. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What is the point of wrapping the your client instance inside another object under the `apolloclient` property?

Comment: @DanielRearden Thank you. That was exactly what was causing the problem.